# HttpUrlConnection redirection does not use request properties of orginial connection

Tags: java, user-agent

Setting properties of a connection do not carry forward to redirected connections

```
HttpURLConnection mConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
mConnection = addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");

InputStream stream = mConnection.getInputStream();
```

if there is a 302 code, `mConnection` is redirected, but the user-agent is `"Java/1.5.0_28"`.

Any suggestion how to handle this?

Comment: did you mean to post `mConnection.addRequestProperty()` instead of `mConnection = addRequestProperty()`  ?

Comment: yes, it should have been that way.

Answer (score 4):

It didn't change, it started out that way.

`addRequestProperty()` won't override the default. Use `setRequestProperty()` instead.

```
HttpURLConnection mConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
mConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
```

Comment: Actually it is correct using add or set for the first connection. It is when the underlying code detects a redirection that the user-agent reverts back to the default.

Comment: No, it's not. You can't have multiple user agent strings. Add does not replace the one that's already there, it adds one.

Comment: The properties are per connection. When redirecting, a NEW connection is created, but the properties are not copied from the old to new connections. I have used a sniffer to see the actual packets so I know this is happening.