# How to set user agent with Jericho parser

Tags: java, html, parsing, agent

I was playing with Jericho's html parser, but I can't find information or rather an example on how to set or change user-agent. I found the class Config, but don't know how to use it, can anyone else give me an example, please?

I managed to parse a website as I want, but I'm not sure whether Jericho's parser adds a user agent. As you might know I want a proper user agent to prevent a site prohibits me for accessing its content.

Thank you.

Comment: "As you might know I want a proper user agent to prevent a site prohibits me for accessing its content." - This sounds like you are trying to get your program to ignore the content of "robots.txt" on a target website. This is *not* something you should be trying to do. Any program that accesses a web page should obey the content of "robots.txt". The consequences of not doing so may be that the website assumes your program is a spambot, and will block any requests coming from the IP address from which your program is sending requests.

Comment: Jon, thnx for your post, I totally forgot about robots.txt. Anyway, the site I tested with happens to allow to crawl the page (I assume it's for google bot to index). Still, there might be sites that don't allow for some reason, but try to access it anyway by faking as a 'normal' browser. Does anyone know how to do that with Jericho? Thank you. Btw, you should note I don't "steal"  content for misuse and I only do that once a while (like once a few days).

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I had a quick look at the Jericho API, and it looks like in a class called "Source", you can pass in a JDK URLConnection object. URLConnection allows you to set headers on the request, and one of these headers can be "User-Agent". I would take a look at doing it that way. Look at the method "setRequestProperty" and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773800/httpurlconnection-redirection-does-not-use-request-properties-of-orginial-connec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment above, make sure you *always* obey robots.txt. Aside from that, the code you want should look something like this.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

import net.htmlparser.jericho.Element;
import net.htmlparser.jericho.Source;

public class HtmlFun {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
      conn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
      conn.setReadTimeout(1000);
      conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");

      Source source = new Source(conn);
      List elems = source.getAllElements();
      for(Element elem : elems) {
         System.out.println(elem);
      }
   }
}
```

Can't run it from work, due to firewall issues, but I think this should work for you. If not, something similar will do the trick.

Comment: Jon, thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it. I can't vote you up as I need 15 reputation... whatever it is. Anyway I checked your post as solved, once again thank you.

Comment: No worries. Glad to be of help :-)