# Open Non-mobile version of site

Tags: android

I want to open Non-mobile version of site inside android application

I have link in my app and i parse the url with (jericho-html).

When i parse the url for example (example.com) the app parse mobile version on the site(mobile.example.com).

since the mobile version of the site i parse is broken i can't get result.
how do i open the desktop version of the site inside my app?

```
Source source = new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));  
source.fullSequentialParse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
 conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
 Source source = new Source(conn);
```

Taken from [How to set user agent with Jericho parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769538/how-to-set-user-agent-with-jericho-parser)